# snapshot/screenshot with MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, screenshot

I am trying to make a snapshot from a view with a MKMapview to provide a springboard like folder animation when the user selects an annotation.

The official way to make a snapshot of the current window is presented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html). This works fine (though quite slow) unless the mapview is not zoomed in too much and has a "regionThatFits" set. The map & the marker make an unmatched "jump" to the left and the gridlines of the mapview are visible:

Before screenshot:
[image: Before screenshot]

After screenshot:
[image: After screenshot]

I suppose it has something to do with the tiled parts of the map but I don't know how to prevent that behaviour.

Any thoughts?